# SSRS Export to Excel gives different results

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that is run on SSRS and the numbers / everything looks good.  I have the data in a table w/ some grouping / drilldown capability.

My issue is that when I export to Excel, and I open up my groups....there is an extra line!  My summary data is the same from SSRS, but now it looks wrong because there is an extra row.

Regardless of what is in the database....shouldn't the results always be the same?  Has anyone ever encountered this before?

I am using SSRS 2008R2

Answer (score 0):

The results may not always be the same because the rendering extension was not created to cover many different situations and reporting designs.

However, with your situation, make sure you have no overlapping controls, rows, other text-boxes etc.